# ImportError: No module named imgaug

Tags: python

I am trying to use (https://github.com/aleju/imgaug) which I have successfully installed using this command:

```
sudo pip install git+https://github.com/aleju/imgaug
```

output of the command:

> Downloading/unpacking git+https://github.com/aleju/imgaug   Cloning
>   https://github.com/aleju/imgaug to /tmp/pip-PsA5jC-build   Running
>   setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-PsA5jC-build/setup.py) egg_info for package
>   from git+https://github.com/aleju/imgaug
>
> Requirement already satisfied
>   (use --upgrade to upgrade): imgaug==0.2.1 from
>   git+https://github.com/aleju/imgaug in
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
>
> Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): scipy in
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from imgaug==0.2.1)
>
> Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade):
>   scikit-image>=0.11.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from
>   imgaug==0.2.1)
>
> Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy>=1.7.0
>   in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from imgaug==0.2.1)
>
> Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six in
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from imgaug==0.2.1)
>
> Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade):
>   matplotlib>=1.3.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from
>   scikit-image>=0.11.0->imgaug==0.2.1)
>
> Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade):
>   networkx>=1.8 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from
>   scikit-image>=0.11.0->imgaug==0.2.1)
>
> Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade):
>   pillow>=2.1.0 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from
>   scikit-image>=0.11.0->imgaug==0.2.1)
>
> Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade):
>   PyWavelets>=0.4.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from
>   scikit-image>=0.11.0->imgaug==0.2.1)
>
> Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade):
>   python-dateutil in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from
>   matplotlib>=1.3.1->scikit-image>=0.11.0->imgaug==0.2.1)
>
> Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): functools32
>   in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from
>   matplotlib>=1.3.1->scikit-image>=0.11.0->imgaug==0.2.1)
>
> Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): subprocess32
>   in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from
>   matplotlib>=1.3.1->scikit-image>=0.11.0->imgaug==0.2.1)
>
> Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pytz in
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from
>   matplotlib>=1.3.1->scikit-image>=0.11.0->imgaug==0.2.1)
>
> Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cycler>=0.10
>   in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from
>   matplotlib>=1.3.1->scikit-image>=0.11.0->imgaug==0.2.1)
>
> Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade):
>   pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=1.5.6 in
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from
>   matplotlib>=1.3.1->scikit-image>=0.11.0->imgaug==0.2.1)
>
> Cleaning up...

but when I tried to import it using this:

```
from imgaug import augmenters as iaa
```

I am getting the following error:

> File "tesing_imaug.py", line 1, in 
>       from imgaug import augmenters as iaa ImportError: No module named imgaug

Comment: Are you sure you're importing it in `python2.7`?

Comment: Yes, I have just checked it

Comment: Did you try running the script with sudo? `sudo python tesing_imaug.py`

Comment: @JanZeiseweis I did, that did not help.

Answer (score 4):

On Ubuntu with Python 3 just typing `pip3 install imgaug` works.

Answer (score 0):

try to run this before

`$ pip install opencv-python==4.2.0.34`